# Group user defined variables in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Is it possible to group user defined variables and get all variable names and values defined in the group dynamically in a Beanshell sampler. What I really want is to read all variables (name and value) defined in a User defined variable config element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use var.getIterator as well as .getItaration and .incIterator to loop through the available variables in a beanshell pre/post processor.

See 
http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/testelement/VariablesCollection.html 
and 
http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html

for more details on the methods available.